# How long does it take to crack an eight character zip compressed password ？

Tags: zip, passwords, cracking

How long does it take to crack an eight character zip compressed password ？

Passwords consist of uppercase, lowercase, and numbers。
How long does it take to crack with current computer computing power? How to calculate it？

Thank you for your answer

Comment: Do you mean the zip file format? It supports many different compression schemes. You would need to specify which one. Also what would you be running the code on? One Raspberry Pi Zero? A cluster of 10,000 AWS EC2 instances? Your question as written is not answerable. Also, no one in their right mind would use a password like that, with only about 10^14 possible password.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Adler noted, more info is needed for absolute answers. But with a couple of modest assumptions, a *relative* answer is possible.

In practical terms, a random 8-character password for a PKZIP compressed file can be cracked in six days on prosumer-grade hardware (which means that it's too short!). And the information below should enable you to calculate it for your case.

The worst-case keyspace you'd need to exhaust (if no other information is known) is 95^8, or about 6.634 × 10^15.

hashcat currently supports the following zip-related hash types:

```
$ hashcat -hh | egrep -i zip | sort -n
  11600 | 7-Zip                                      | Archive
  13600 | WinZip                                     | Archive
  17200 | PKZIP (Compressed)                         | Archive
  17210 | PKZIP (Uncompressed)                       | Archive
  17220 | PKZIP (Compressed Multi-File)              | Archive
  17225 | PKZIP (Mixed Multi-File)                   | Archive
  17230 | PKZIP (Mixed Multi-File Checksum-Only)     | Archive
  20500 | PKZIP Master Key                           | Archive
  20510 | PKZIP Master Key (6 byte optimization)     | Archive
  23001 | SecureZIP AES-128                          | Archive
  23002 | SecureZIP AES-192                          | Archive
  23003 | SecureZIP AES-256                          | Archive
```

... which benchmark at the following hashrates on two RTX 4090s:

```
$ hashcat --version
v6.2.6-846-g4d412c8e0

$ for mode in 11600 17220 17200 17225 17230 17210 20500 20510 23001 23002 23003 13600; do hashcat --quiet -b -m ${mode}; done
---------------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 11600 (7-Zip) [Iterations: 16384]
---------------------------------------------

Speed.#1.........:  2592.2 kH/s (91.15ms) @ Accel:64 Loops:4096 Thr:128 Vec:1
Speed.#2.........:  2500.3 kH/s (95.12ms) @ Accel:64 Loops:4096 Thr:128 Vec:1
Speed.#*.........:  5092.5 kH/s

-------------------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 17220 (PKZIP (Compressed Multi-File))
-------------------------------------------------

Speed.#1.........: 45636.1 MH/s (46.69ms) @ Accel:1024 Loops:512 Thr:32 Vec:1
Speed.#2.........: 44164.4 MH/s (48.25ms) @ Accel:1024 Loops:512 Thr:32 Vec:1
Speed.#*.........: 89800.5 MH/s

--------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 17200 (PKZIP (Compressed))
--------------------------------------

Speed.#1.........:  6287.0 MH/s (18.49ms) @ Accel:28 Loops:1024 Thr:32 Vec:1
Speed.#2.........:  6178.8 MH/s (18.73ms) @ Accel:28 Loops:1024 Thr:32 Vec:1
Speed.#*.........: 12465.8 MH/s

--------------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 17225 (PKZIP (Mixed Multi-File))
--------------------------------------------

Speed.#1.........: 54859.4 MH/s (77.88ms) @ Accel:1024 Loops:1024 Thr:32 Vec:1
Speed.#2.........: 53166.2 MH/s (80.35ms) @ Accel:1024 Loops:1024 Thr:32 Vec:1
Speed.#*.........:   108.0 GH/s

----------------------------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 17230 (PKZIP (Mixed Multi-File Checksum-Only))
----------------------------------------------------------

Speed.#1.........: 61360.1 MH/s (34.66ms) @ Accel:128 Loops:512 Thr:256 Vec:1
Speed.#2.........: 59158.4 MH/s (35.95ms) @ Accel:128 Loops:512 Thr:256 Vec:1
Speed.#*.........:   120.5 GH/s

----------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 17210 (PKZIP (Uncompressed))
----------------------------------------

Speed.#1.........:  8513.4 MH/s (31.20ms) @ Accel:512 Loops:64 Thr:64 Vec:1
Speed.#2.........:  8279.8 MH/s (32.08ms) @ Accel:512 Loops:64 Thr:64 Vec:1
Speed.#*.........: 16793.2 MH/s

------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 20500 (PKZIP Master Key)
------------------------------------

Speed.#1.........:   530.9 GH/s (7.82ms) @ Accel:1024 Loops:1024 Thr:32 Vec:1
Speed.#2.........:   513.9 GH/s (8.09ms) @ Accel:1024 Loops:1024 Thr:32 Vec:1
Speed.#*.........:  1044.8 GH/s

----------------------------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 20510 (PKZIP Master Key (6 byte optimization))
----------------------------------------------------------

Speed.#1.........:   122.0 GH/s (34.88ms) @ Accel:512 Loops:1024 Thr:64 Vec:1
Speed.#2.........:   118.0 GH/s (36.04ms) @ Accel:512 Loops:1024 Thr:64 Vec:1
Speed.#*.........:   240.0 GH/s

-------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 23001 (SecureZIP AES-128)
-------------------------------------

Speed.#1.........:  7110.7 MH/s (75.21ms) @ Accel:16 Loops:1024 Thr:256 Vec:1
Speed.#2.........:  6880.1 MH/s (77.72ms) @ Accel:16 Loops:1024 Thr:256 Vec:1
Speed.#*.........: 13990.8 MH/s

-------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 23002 (SecureZIP AES-192)
-------------------------------------

Speed.#1.........:  5282.7 MH/s (50.51ms) @ Accel:16 Loops:512 Thr:256 Vec:1
Speed.#2.........:  5113.5 MH/s (52.20ms) @ Accel:16 Loops:512 Thr:256 Vec:1
Speed.#*.........: 10396.2 MH/s

-------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 23003 (SecureZIP AES-256)
-------------------------------------

Speed.#1.........:  4562.9 MH/s (58.54ms) @ Accel:8 Loops:1024 Thr:256 Vec:1
Speed.#2.........:  4408.0 MH/s (60.59ms) @ Accel:8 Loops:1024 Thr:256 Vec:1
Speed.#*.........:  8971.0 MH/s

--------------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 13600 (WinZip) [Iterations: 999]
--------------------------------------------

Speed.#1.........: 19108.6 kH/s (50.69ms) @ Accel:16 Loops:999 Thr:512 Vec:1
Speed.#2.........: 17769.8 kH/s (52.15ms) @ Accel:16 Loops:999 Thr:512 Vec:1
Speed.#*.........: 36878.3 kH/s
```

Once you determine your file type and hardware, you now have the elements necessary to calculate the worst-case exhaustion time (adjusting your assumptions to match your case).

For example, on this hardware, the 17210 (PKZIP compressed) format can be attacked at 12465.8 MH/s (millions of hashes per second). For this password, you have to exhaust a maximum of 95^8 possibilities.  Dividing by 60 to get minutes, 60 to get hours, and 24 to get days ... yields **six days**:

[(95^8) / 12465000000 / 60 / 60 / 24](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%2895%5E8%29%20%2F%2012465000000%2F60%2F60%2F24) = ~6.16 days